# Get local image's height, width and all pixels's rgb

Tags: javascript, html

I have found the following code that let's the user load an image from his computer.
https://jsfiddle.net/8Lw42kcv/

```
<input id="files" type="file">
<output id="list"></output>
```

```
function handleFileSelect(evt){
var files=evt.target.files
for(var i=0,f;f=files[i];i++){
var reader=new FileReader()
reader.onload=(function(theFile){
return function(e){
var span=document.createElement('span')
span.innerHTML=['<img class="thumb"src="',e.target.result,
'"title="',escape(theFile.name),'"/>'].join('')
document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span,null)
}
})(f)
reader.readAsDataURL(f)
}
}
document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change',handleFileSelect,false)
```

Now, what I really want is not to show the image, but to read it's size (height and width) and also every pixel's rgb (red, green, blue) value.

`e.target.result` = the link of the image converted to base 64.

How can I, `alert()` the chosen image's height, width and red, green and blue of the pixel 1,1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this would be useful for you.

```js
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
 var files = evt.target.files
 for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
  var reader = new FileReader()
  reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
   return function(e) {
   // var span = document.createElement('span')
   // span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb"src="', e.target.result,
   //  '"title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'
   // ].join('')
   // document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null)
   getInfo(e.target.result)
     }
  })(f)
  reader.readAsDataURL(f)
 }
}
document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false)

function getInfo(pic) {
 var ctxt = canvas.getContext('2d');
 var img = new Image;
 img.src = pic;
 img.onload = function() {
  ctxt.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  var data = ctxt.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height).data;
  var red = data[0],
     green = data[1],
     blue = data[2];
  alert("hight is " + img.height + "px,width is " + img.width + "px,pix(1,1)'s r:"+red + ',g:' + green + ',b:' + blue);
 }
}
```

```html
<input id="files" type="file">
<output id="list"></output>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: @Isv Perfect! It works as I intended and I only need to change the zeros in the line `var data = ctxt.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height).data;` to change the pixel. I noticed that the result of a .jpg type image can be a little different comparing to when I open the image with paint and check the pixel's rgb but then I saved the image as .png and the rgb got exactly the same. I also only needed for .png so that's no problem if it is even one.